# mysql indexing timestamp column that update frequently

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing, timestamp, sql-update

I am using mysql (innoDB). I have a large users table with these columns:
user_id,last_action_time. The user_id is unique primary key. The  table has about 5 millions row.

```
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id          | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_action_time | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Whenever a user makes an action on the site i update the timestamp in the last_action_time column.
For the Back-office system I need to show the last 30 users that made an action on the site.
Something like this:

```
SELECT user_id,last_action_time FROM user_table ORDER BY last_action_time DESC LIMIT 30
```

This takes a lot of time. I thought about indexing the last_action_time but I fear I will have problems because the the last_action_time column is getting update very frequently. How can can I have a column that has index but also getting updated a lot

Comment: Depends on how heavy your data gets manipulated and if you can live with the slower updates.  You can always drop the index later.

Comment: And you could also give *Partitioning* a try.

Comment: First time I hear about Partitioning i will check it

Answer (score 2):

If you need to search on the column `last_action_time`, it needs to have an index. It is true, that updating the index will slow down slightly every update query.

If you hesitate to create an index or not just compare the frequency of your queries with their efficiency.

- update: each updated line, you will update one pointer in the index. The efficiency penalty will be very low, as long as your index is in memory (and it certainly is, unless you're running on *very very* few memory).
- select: your select query will need to do a full table scan instead of an index read. Test how much you will speed up the query. It could be 100 times faster or 1000x faster, depending on the size of the table.

Now to the decision:

- the very small penalty for the update query will not weight out the immense benefit for the select query. Think also about other problems with full table scan (cache invalidation).
- if you have 1 select query for 1000 or 10'000 updates, you can start think of dropping the index. If you select more frequently, don't even hesitate.